# Definition of a Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: geometry, manifolds, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Apologies if this is a basic question, but I'd really like to clarify the exact meaning of what a Cartesian coordinate system is.
Heuristically, is it correct to say that a Cartesian coordinate system is "Euclidean geometry with coordinates" and so by definition the geometry that we are studying has to be Euclidean (i.e. Euclidean metric, parallel postulate, etc. must hold) in order to use this coordinate system. Also, more mathematically, is it correct to say that a Cartesian coordinate system is a special kind of mapping between points of Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^{n}$ and real space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Such a coordinate map makes the intrinsic spatial distance between two points in $\mathbb{E}^{n}$ be directly reflected by the ‘numerical distance’ between their numerical coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

If this is correct then I can understand why Cartesian coordinate maps cannot generally be used for patches on manifolds as the geometry will generally be non-Euclidean. As such the homeomorphisms (coordinate maps) from the patch on the manifold to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ will necessarily deform the patch, consequently intrinsic distances between points, angles, etc. will not preserved and so Cartesian coordinates cannot be used.

Comment: This is hardly a basic question IMHO. +1)

Comment: @DavidH        I thought that too, but I was worried other people might feel differently.

Comment: I'll note that "coordinates" alone do not require Euclidean geometry. In the hyperbolic plane, eg, one can designate a pair of orthogonal *axes*. From each point $P$ in the plane, one can drop perpendiculars to these axes; the lengths of these perpendiculars, along with appropriate signs for a given quadrant, provide perfectly-useful $(x,y)$-coordinates for $P$. The significant distinguishing characteristic between these coords and coords on the Euclidean plane is the associated *distance formula*. Clearly, $\sqrt{(x_0-x_1)^2+(y_0-y_1)^2}$ doesn't apply to hyperbolic coordinates. (What does?)

Comment: @Blue          That was kind of my thinking, that Cartesian coordinates require the notion of the usual Pythagorean distance formula, which doesn't hold for non-Euclidean geometries and hence why Cartesian coordinate maps are not possible for such geometries?!

Comment: @Will: Well, that gets to your question of just how exactly is a Cartesian coordinate system *defined*. If "Cartesian coordinates" implies "Pythagorean distance formula", then it's a Euclideans-only club. Personally, I have no problem calling the hyperbolic coordinate system "Cartesian", since I think Descartes' fundamental conceptual innovation was in assigning *coordinates* to a space, allowing us to "do geometry" with algebra; the distance formula is something we *derive* based on the associated geometry. Perhaps I'm too willing to be loose with some formal definition, though.

Comment: @Blue          I think the issue I have found about that though is many mathematical texts seem to imply what I originally wrote, as they say that in general one cannot construct a Cartesian coordinate map from a manifold with  non-Euclidean geometry into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but none of them explicitly explain why which is very frustrating!

Comment: @Will: I up-voted your question, because I think your frustration is valid. I'm just saying that I, *personally*, consider "Cartesian coordinates" to be independent of "Pythagorean distance formula". These texts you've read seem have me in the minority; I'm okay with that. :) Come to think of it, if I were to discuss hyperbolic coordinates with someone, I might well drop "Cartesian" as a descriptor, just to avoid the kind of confusion you're facing. Even so, I'd expect authors to be more explicit with their assumptions. I, like you, await an answer with better insights on the matter.

Comment: @Blue          Cheers for doing that! Sorry, I didn't explain my last comment well. The requirement of a Euclidean distance being defined was my own attempt to try and understand the situation. The texts I've read talk about Cartesian coordinate systems but don't explicitly define what they mean by "a Cartesian coordinate system". They do, however state that in general it is not possible to construct a Cartesian coordinate map between a patch on a manifold to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but again they do not explicitly explain why unfortunately.

Comment: According to Wikipedia there is no such thing as $\mathbb{E}^{n}$, it is just  [$\mathbb{E}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space), or just called a Euclidean space. There is a [way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Technical_definition) to derive the dimension of a Euclidean space, but it is not tied to a Cartesian product (a Cartesian product only applies to $n$-tuples and $ \mathbb R^n$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the mathematical literature, the term "Cartesian coordinates" is used most frequently to refer simply to the standard coordinate functions on $\mathbb R^n$, namely the functions $x^1,\dots,x^n\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ defined by $x^i(a^1,\dots,a^n) = a^i$.  Somewhat less frequently, I've also seen the term used to refer to any coordinate system on $\mathbb R^n$ obtained by composing the standard coordinates with a rigid motion, which can also be characterized as those coordinates for which the standard coordinate vectors $\partial/\partial x^1,\dots,\partial/\partial x^n$ are orthonormal.

The point is that it only makes sense to talk about "Cartesian coordinates" on $\mathbb R^n$ itself, or on an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$.  On an arbitrary smooth manifold, the term has no meaning. Of course, on any smooth manifold $M$, each point has a neighborhood $U$ on which we can find a smooth coordinate chart, and such a chart allows us to identify each point $p\in U$ with its coordinate values $(x^1(p),\dots,x^n(p))\in\mathbb R^n$, and thus to temporarily identify $U$ with an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$; but we would not call these coordinates "Cartesian coordinates on $M$."

If your manifold $M$ is endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$, then there is more that can be said. For example, one could ask whether it's possible to find a coordinate chart in which the given Riemannian metric has the same coordinate expression as the Euclidean metric: $g= (dx^1)^2 + \dots + (dx^n)^2$. If this is the case, then geodesics and distances *within this coordinate neighborhood* are given by the same formulas as they are in Euclidean space; but that might not hold true elsewhere on the manifold. I think this might be the question you're getting at in your last paragraph, although I would not call these "Cartesian coordinates" because they don't have an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ as their domain. Off the top of my head, I don't know of any standard nomenclature for such coordinates, but it wouldn't be inconsistent to call them "Euclidean coordinates" or "flat coordinates."

It's a basic theorem of Riemannian geometry that it is impossible to find such coordinates unless the curvature tensor of the Riemannian metric is identically zero on the open subset $U$. You'll find a proof of this fact in virtually any book on Riemannian geometry, such as my *Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature* (Theorem 7.3). If you want a treatment that doesn't use so much of the machinery of Riemannian manifolds, my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* has a proof that it's impossible to find Euclidean coordinates for the ordinary $2$-sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ (Proposition 13.19 and Corollary 13.20).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I think it's cleared up a few things for me. Is it correct to say that when one constructs a homeomorphism from a patch on a manifold to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ this defines a coordinate system (or coordinate map) that labels points in the patch by coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$...

Comment: ...If the geometry on the manifold is non-Euclidean then when one talks of it being locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (Euclidean space), is this the statement that the topology of the manifold and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are locally identical and not a statement about the geometry being locally Euclidean (assuming that a metric has been defined)?

Comment: @Will: Yes, as Peter Franek pointed out in his answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332769/meaning-of-locally-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrn), a homeomorphism is by definition simply a map that is bijective, continuous, and with continuous inverse. This definition says absolutely nothing about geometry, Euclidean or otherwise.

Comment: So does the geometry determine the coordinate maps that one can construct? Would it be in some sense correct to say that Cartesian coordinates are only possible if the manifold is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as they are global coordinates? (For Cartesian coordinates to be applicable is it in any sense correct to say that the space has to be locally flat, i.e. have a Euclidean metric?)

Comment: No, the geometry has no bearing on the coordinate maps you can construct, because coordinates do not have to have any direct relationship to a metric. (The definition of a "coordinate chart" makes no reference to a metric.) You can use Cartesian coordinates if and only if your manifold is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, regardless of whether it's endowed with the Euclidean metric, some other metric, or no metric. What is true is that unless the metric you're interested in on that open set is the Euclidean one, then Cartesian coordinates will not have any relationship with the metric.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry for the possibly basic questions, but it's really been a sticking point for me. I think part of my confusion is that in a lot of notes that I've read, coordinate maps from a patch on a manifold to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are depicted as mapping into a rectangular plane (lower dimensional depiction of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) which my brain unfortunately immediately associates with Euclidean space and Cartesian coordinates...

Comment: ... I've seen examples where the sphere $S^{2}$ is treated as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ in which case we can define a coordinate chart $(\theta ,\phi)\mapsto (\sin (\theta )\cos (\phi ) , \sin (\theta )\sin (\phi ) , \cos (\theta ))$, is this just a pullback from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ so that we can use Cartesian coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (with coordinate transformations from spherical polar coordinates)?

Comment: This is just the inverse of a coordinate chart on $S^2$. In advanced differential geometry, a coordinate chart for an $n$-manifold is defined as a homeomorphism from an open subset of the manifold to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. The inverse map is usually called a "patch" or a "local parametrization." Confusingly, in elementary books about surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$, the word "chart" is sometimes used for a parametrization, but it's better to avoid that usage.

Comment: So $(\theta , \phi)$ are the local coordinates on a patch of $S^{2}$ then? I find this quite confusing as I thought that a point on a manifold could only be labelled by an $n$-tuple once it had been mapped into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (i.e. $p\mapsto (x^{1},\ldots ,x^{n})$ , where $p\in M$ and  $(x^{1},\ldots ,x^{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and so in the sphere example I thought that $(\theta , \phi)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and not  $(\theta , \phi)\in S^{2}$)?

Comment: So is it the case then that we locally parametrise a manifold by a number (equal to the dimension of the manifold) of parameters and then use these parameters to define a local map in to  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, for example, in the case of $S^{2}$ the local map from a patch of $S^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is of the form $(\theta ,\phi )\mapsto (x^{1},x^{2})\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: In general, yes. But in this case, since $S^2$ is literally a subset of $\mathbb R^3$, "locally parametrizing $S^2$" means constructing a map from an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^2\subseteq\mathbb R^3$. That's what the map $(\theta,\phi)\mapsto (\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta)$ is.

Comment: So what would the coordinate map look like in the general case? Would one choose a set of parameters $(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})\in V\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\gamma : V\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow U\subset M\; ,\;\; (u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})\mapsto p$ and then the homeomorphism is defined by $(u^{1},\ldots,u^{n})\mapsto (x^{1},\ldots , x^{n})$?

Comment: It would be more accurate to write the local homeomorphism from $U\subset M$ to $V\subset\mathbb R^n$ as $\gamma(u^1,\dots,u^n) \mapsto (u^1,\dots, u^n)$.  Of course, $\gamma(u^1,\dots,u^n)$ will have some expression in terms of the coordinates of $\mathbb R^r$.

Comment: So in the case of $S^{2}$ is the 3-tuple $(\sin (\theta)\cos (\phi), \sin (\theta)\sin (\phi), \cos (\theta))$ a parametrisation of a point in a patch of $S^{2}$ and $(\theta ,\phi)$ it's coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? So is the takeaway point really that Cartesian coordinates can only be used when the manifold we are studying is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and in the case where a metric is defined, they can only be used when studying with $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the Euclidean metric defined on it...

Comment: ... Furthermore, in general, we can only use Euclidean (flat) coordinates (a generalisation of Cartesian coordinates for general manifolds?) when the local curvature is zero?! Would it be in any sense correct to say that the Cartesian (or Euclidean) coordinates can only be used when Euclid's postulates hold, in particular, the parallel postulate (without it one would not be able to construct Cartesian coordinate axes, right?)